# AIS directly on QGIS

Tags: qgis, ais

I'm looking to have AIS data ( Carbon + from True Heading) in real time on QGIS.

From AIS I got the data as following:

```
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,35?7p455h53k<LH>;dR`wbgoP000,0*7F
```

After using a specific software to read it that's how it come back:

```
466004000;under way ;128°'; 0.0kt;25.020450N;51.645125E;306.9°;511°;59s; 150324 000000;serial#1(A)[1]
```

It seems that i can't load the txt file as coordinates are with "N" & "E".

Did someone tried already to import data from AIS in real time on QGIS?

Likely, someone will know how to transform the data directly from AIS, without using a specific software to read it.

Answer (score 1):

In the QGIS `delimited text` import dialogue, you can write `E N`in the field for `other delimiters`. This may destroy other fields with text content.

Alternatively, you can use a good text editor like notepad++ to replace all `N;` with `;` and `E;` with `;` before importing.